# Website not being able to login into the REST application

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am developing a web application. My main application is a REST application. Unlike traditional web development, my website connects to my rest application to POST, DELETE, PUT or GET data.

Now, when i POST my username and password to my REST application through a desktop application called Postman(https://www.getpostman.com/) and then GET the account data, it works perfectly fine and I am able to retrieve the data.

But when my website connects to my REST app through cURL library. It is not able to GET any data because the website shows not logged in.

I don't know why Postman and my website are behaving differently even though they are getting data from same REST application.

Note that the sessions are in REST application only, so my website doesnt use any native sessions.

Here are my functions in my website:

```
function process_api_get($base_url,$extension)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $base_url . $extension,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET'
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

 // echo '<pre>';
 // print_r($resp);
 // exit;

return json_decode($resp);
}
function process_api_post($input,$base_url,$extension)
{
    $obj = json_encode($input);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $obj);       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $base_url . $extension);
//    
    if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name().'='.$_COOKIE[session_name()].'; path=/');

    session_write_close();

    $result = curl_exec($ch);


    curl_close($ch);

  return json_decode($result); 
}

function process_api_put($input,$base_url,$extension)
{

  $obj = json_encode($input);
    $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");   
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $obj);       
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0');   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $base_url . $extension);
  if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name().'='.$_COOKIE[session_name()].'; path=/');

  session_write_close(); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    session_start();
  return json_decode($result); 

}
function process_api_delete($input,$base_url,$extension)
{
    $obj = json_encode($input);
    $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");   
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $obj);       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $base_url . $extension);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
  return json_decode($result); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. When you ask a question and receive help, don't just leave or it will prevent you from getting help in the future. These answers take a long time to test and write.  If my answer is helpful, select it (upvote if you like). If it is not helpful, leave feedback about what's unclear, wrong or missing.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a difference between what Postman sends and what your website does when making the request. What I would suggest:

1. Reset everything.
2. `POST` username/pass then `GET` data with Postman. Record the request headers and parameters that your REST service received from each request into a log file.
3. Reset everything.
4. Repeat step 2 but making requests from your website instead.
5. Compare the headers and parameters for discrepancies between what Postman and what your website sent.

In order to record request headers and parameters, call a function that executes the code below at the top of the PHP scripts that receive the `POST` and the `GET` request:

```
$filepath = 'path/to/request_logs.txt'; //save loction
$file_contents =  
"=========== ".strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")." ============".PHP_EOL
                    ."Request Headers: ".PHP_EOL
                    .print_r(http_get_request_headers(),true)
                    .PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL
                    ."Request Parameters: ".PHP_EOL
                    .print_r($_REQUEST,true)
                    .PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents($filepath,$file_contents,FILE_APPEND); //log the request
```

Once you figure out what differs between Postman's requests and your website's requests, you'll find the problem.